# As if ALT doesn't get released - using shortcut keys / Alt+key combination

Tags: c#, .net, shortcut, alt

My .net (C#) GUI has both Alt+n and Alt+a defined as shortcuts(E.g. two buttons named "&Add" and "&Notes").

The problem is that after the user clicks Alt+n and the corresponding code executes, then it seems that "ALT" is still in "pressed" mode. If the user will now click only the "a" character (not the "Alt+a" combination) still the code for the "Alt+a" combination will execute.

Pressing "ESC" after the "Alt+n" will release the "ALT from it's weird behavior. Afterwards pressing "a" will not have that "Alt+a" effect anymore.

Why is this happening ?
How can I prevent this ?

Thanks !

Note: obviously Alt+a and Alt+n are only examples. this happens with whatever hotkey.

Comment: What's your code for checking whether the `Alt` key is pressed or not?

Comment: Notice how the A and the N get underlined when you press the Alt key?  And *stay* underlined when you release it?  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for answering.<BR>
I'm not checking it by code. I just press the keys.
1. Pressing [Alt]+[n]
   => this causes the desired effect of the key combination.
2. Pressing [a]
   => the behavior is as if I pressed [Alt]+[a]

Comment: if it has to do with the "concatenated" shortcuts, like VC# 2010 has (e.g. [Ctrl][E] -> [C], for commenting out a region), then how do I cancel that ?
otherwise, what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When you press only Alt key, does your buttons show "A" and "N" underlined? It could be related to your windows settings. Go to "Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use" and try different settings there.